# Selenium web driver - Action : Why does Action Work only for web pages having ul and li tags?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Actions (Selenium web driver) work for web pages that has ul,li tags only ...but not for web pages that don't have these tags...and for such kind of web pages we  have to use java scripts for "On mouse "events?Can anybody answer me why actions doesn't work if ul or li tags are not there for web page?I have researched a lot and found no answers for it..Any help?

Comment: Yes ...I mean built in Action class. It works fine for web pages that have ul and li tags but for the web pages that do not have these tags we need to use Java Script Executor for Mouse movements automation...I just want to know why Actions doesn't support web pages that  do not have the these tags?

Comment: I'm not aware of that. Where did you get that from? Source? What binding are you using?

Comment: You can try it ....www.espncricinfo.com site does not have ul or li tags (Check the source code of the pages)...Actions would not work for automating this site...We have to use Java Script Executor...I do not know why Action Class does not work for web pages that do not have these tags.....

Comment: Selenium web driver 2.32 ...Firefox 11....and in www.espncricinfo.com click countries and click india and view the source code you will not find any ul,li tags there.... Im sorry I have formattd my system I do not have the source code ..but I'm going to attend interviews on Selenium so if I'm asked this question that why actions do not work for sites that does not have these tags ?...so wanted to know if there is any logic involved behind this concept....